# Doctrine query with LIKE on many to many - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to do a join on 2 relations with a like. It's not working quite as I expected. I'll get right into it since code is easier to read.

```
class Video
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many Videos have Many Tags.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="video_tag")
     *
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * Many Videos have Many Categories.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="video_category")
     *
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $categories;

    ...
}
```

---

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many Tags have Many Videos.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Video", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $videos;

    ...
}
```

---

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many Tags have Many Videos.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Video", mappedBy="categories")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $videos;

    ...
}
```

3 tables are involved here: `Video` `Tag` and `Category`

A `Video` can have many `Tag` and many `Category`. While `Tag` and `Category` can belong to many `Video`.

Pretty standard many to many setup using junction tables.

I'm trying to get an advanced search form to work properly. The problem is when I add a `LIKE` in the query.

Here's the long versions:

```
  if(isset($data['ti']) && !empty($data['ti'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('v.title LIKE :title');
        $qb->setParameter(':title', '%' . str_replace('%', '', $data['t']) . '%');
    }

    if(isset($data['t']) && !empty($data['t'])) {
        if(stristr($data['t'], ',')) {
            $tags = explode(',', $data['t']);
            $tags = array_filter(array_map('trim', $tags));

            $qb->leftJoin('v.tags', 'tags')
                ->andWhere('tags.name IN (:tags)');
            $qb->setParameter(':tags', $tags, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
        }
    }

    if(isset($data['c']) && !empty($data['c'])) {
        if(stristr($data['c'], ',')) {
            $categories = explode(',', $data['c']);
            $categories = array_filter(array_map('trim', $categories));

            $qb->leftJoin('v.categories', 'categories')
                ->andWhere('categories.name IN (:categories)');
            $qb->setParameter(':categories', $categories, Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
        }
    }

    if(isset($data['u']) && !empty($data['u'])) {
        if(strtolower($data['u']) === 'asc') {
            $qb->addOrderBy('v.createdAt', 'ASC');
        } else {
            $qb->addOrderBy('v.createdAt', 'DESC');
        }
    }

    if(isset($data['v']) && !empty($data['v'])) {
        if(strtolower($data['v']) === 'asc') {
            $qb->addOrderBy('v.views', 'ASC');
        } else {
            $qb->addOrderBy('v.views', 'DESC');
        }
    }

    if(isset($data['d']) && !empty($data['d'])) {
        switch (strtolower($data['d'])){
            case 'any':
                break; // any duration is acceptable
            case '60_180':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 60');
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration <= 180');
                break;
            case '180_360':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 180');
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration <= 360');
                break;
            case '360_540':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 360');
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration <= 540');
                break;
            case '540_720':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 540');
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration <= 720');
                break;
            case '720_900':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 720');
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration <= 900');
                break;
            case '900_999999':
                $qb->andWhere('v.duration >= 900');
                break;
        }
    }
```

---

And the short more reabable version:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->andWhere('v.title LIKE :title') // this is the problematic part
    ->setParameter(':title', '%' . str_replace('%', '', $data['t']) . '%')
    ->leftJoin('v.tags', 'tags')
    ->andWhere('tags.name IN (:tags)')
    ->leftJoin('v.categories', 'categories')
    ->andWhere('categories.name IN (:categories)')
    ->addOrderBy('v.createdAt', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('v.views', 'ASC')
    ->andWhere('v.duration >= 60')
    ->andWhere('v.duration <= 180')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

And the SQL itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM   video v0_ 
       LEFT JOIN video_tag v2_ 
              ON v0_.id = v2_.video_id 
       LEFT JOIN tag t1_ 
              ON t1_.id = v2_.tag_id 
       LEFT JOIN video_category v4_ 
              ON v0_.id = v4_.video_id 
       LEFT JOIN category c3_ 
              ON c3_.id = v4_.category_id 
WHERE  v0_.title LIKE ? 
       AND t1_.NAME IN ( ? ) 
       AND c3_.NAME IN ( ? ) 
ORDER  BY v0_.createdat DESC, 
          v0_.views DESC
```

---

The result of the above query is this:

```
Array()
```

The result of the above query WITHOUT the like is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [views] => 0
            [title] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            [thumbnail] => 102ec57b8e94bf267b7bc5b348e0ebbc51c0b2f11db10a425f99ef796f293cd1f94147269fd34907.jpeg
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            [path] => 025a66a75077ab3758d32b7686f96049b47c66f7bf87e98404dadde02b5905871097d59a86707924.mp4
            [isDeleted] => 0
            [slug] => lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet%2C-consectetur-adipiscing-elit%2C-sed-do-eiusmod-tempor-incididunt-ut-labore-
            [createdAt] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-09-27 17:38:24.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [duration] => 30
            [md5CheckSum] => d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
        )

)
```

Here's what the search form looks like(if it helps)

[image]

---

Admittedly I'm not very good at SQL but I assumed this would work. Obviously I was wrong.

I'm not against doing this another way. But I'd like to avoid doing raw SQLs if possible.

If a `LIKE` is avoidable I'm also fine with that. Since it's abysmally slow on large data sets.

Any help is appreciated.

Example data recieved from the form:

```
Array
(
[ti] => Lorem
[t] => tag_0,
[c] => category_0,
[u] => DESC
[v] => DESC
[d] => any
)
```

Comment: this would make perfect sense, if `$data['t']` is actually garbage (check in profiler, you should be able to display a runnable query). regarding the speed: do you have a fulltext index on title? that would help performance

Comment: I do have a fulltext index on title. I didn't do an explain yet so I'm not sure if it's actually using the index or not. Remains to be seen. I'm absolutely sure that `$data['t']` is not garbage. I've edited the question with a simple search. See the edit at the bottom.

Comment: I think I found your typo ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo in your long version?

```
if(isset($data['ti']) && !empty($data['ti'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('v.title LIKE :title');
    $qb->setParameter(':title', '%' . str_replace('%', '', $data['t']) . '%');
    //                                                            ^ this should be ti
}
```

Comment: it's usually something really dumb. that's why I always look at the runnable query in the profiler, you would have noticed there ;o/

Comment: Lesson learned. The profiler is my friend. If only this silly Vagrant had enough memory to actually support xDebug. Thanks again. Saved me a bunch of headache.